# FFMPEG audio conversion is taking too much time

Tags: android, audio, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

How to make the audio conversion ultrafast?

It is now taking more than 2 minutes for converting an audio around 2mb in size.

The command i'm using for execution of conversion is

```
String[] cmd = {"-y", "-i", audioPath, outputPath};
```

How to preset the ultrafast mode?

While i'm trying it like

```
String[] cmd = {"-y", "-i", audioPath,"-preset", "ultrafast" ,outputPath};
```

It is taking same time itself.

Using the library https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java

Log:

> D: ffmpeg version n3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
> D:   built with gcc 4.8 (GCC) D:   configuration: --target-os=linux
> --cross-prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-
> --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot
> --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include
> -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib
> -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags= D:   libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103 D:   libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102 D:   libavformat    57. 25.100
> / 57. 25.100 D:   libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101 D:
> libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100 D:   libswscale      4.  0.100
> /  4.  0.100 D:   libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101 D:
> libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100 D: [mp3 @ 0xf2a25000] Skipping
> 0 bytes of junk at 33. D: [mp3 @ 0xf2a25000] Estimating duration from
> bitrate, this may be inaccurate D: Input #0, mp3, from
> '/storage/emulated/0/Bluetooth1/Aluva Puzha Song with Lyrics  Premam
> Malayalam Movie Song 2015 ft Nivin Pauly.mp3': D:   Metadata: D:
> encoder         : Lavf52.64.2 D:   Duration: 00:03:03.28, start:
> 0.000000, bitrate: 128 kb/s D:     Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s D: Codec AVOption preset (Set the encoding
> preset (cf. x264 --fullhelp)) specified for output file #0
> (/storage/emulated/0/SACLO.m4a) has not been used for any stream. The
> most likely reason is either wrong type (e.g. a video option with no
> video streams) or that it is a private option of some encoder which
> was not actually used for any stream. D: Output #0, ipod, to
> '/storage/emulated/0/SACLO.m4a': D:   Metadata: D:     encoder
> : Lavf57.25.100 D:     Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a /
> 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s D:     Metadata: D:
> encoder         : Lavc57.24.102 aac D: Stream mapping: D:   Stream
>
> ## 0:0 -> #0:0 (mp3 (native) -> aac (native)) D: Press [q] to stop, [?] for help D: size=       6kB time=00:00:01.78 bitrate=  25.6kbits/s
>
> speed=3.54x     D: size=      18kB time=00:00:02.53 bitrate=
> 57.1kbits/s speed=2.51x     D: size=      30kB time=00:00:03.32 bitrate=  74.1kbits/s speed=2.18x     D: size=      42kB
> time=00:00:04.08 bitrate=  84.9kbits/s speed=2.02x     D: size=
> 50kB time=00:00:04.57 bitrate=  89.5kbits/s speed=1.81x     D: size=
> 61kB time=00:00:05.27 bitrate=  95.4kbits/s speed=1.73x     D: size=
> 70kB time=00:00:05.82 bitrate=  98.6kbits/s speed=1.64x     D: size=
> 80kB time=00:00:06.45 bitrate= 101.4kbits/s speed=1.59x     D: size=
> 91kB time=00:00:07.17 bitrate= 104.4kbits/s speed=1.57x     D: size=
> 103kB time=00:00:07.91 bitrate= 106.8kbits/s speed=1.56x     D: size=
> 115kB time=00:00:08.68 bitrate= 108.9kbits/s speed=1.56x     D: size=
> 128kB time=00:00:09.49 bitrate= 110.7kbits/s speed=1.56x     D: size=
> 137kB time=00:00:10.05 bitrate= 111.6kbits/s speed=1.52x     D: size=
> 151kB time=00:00:10.91 bitrate= 113.0kbits/s speed=1.53x     D: size=
> 160kB time=00:00:11.47 bitrate= 113.9kbits/s speed=1.51x     D: size=
> 170kB time=00:00:12.14 bitrate= 114.9kbits/s speed= 1.5x     D: size=
> 184kB time=00:00:12.97 bitrate= 115.8kbits/s speed= 1.5x     D: size=
> 196kB time=00:00:13.79 bitrate= 116.6kbits/s speed=1.51x     D: size=
> 209kB time=00:00:14.62 bitrate= 117.3kbits/s speed=1.52x     D: size=
> 222kB time=00:00:15.44 bitrate= 118.0kbits/s speed=1.52x     D: size=
> 235kB time=00:00:16.20 bitrate= 118.5kbits/s speed=1.52x     D: size=
> 247kB time=00:00:16.99 bitrate= 119.0kbits/s speed=1.52x     D: size=
> 256kB time=00:00:17.60 bitrate= 119.4kbits/s speed=1.51x     D: size=
> 266kB time=00:00:18.18 bitrate= 119.7kbits/s speed=1.49x     D: size=
> 276kB time=00:00:18.85 bitrate= 120.0kbits/s speed=1.48x     D: size=
> 287kB time=00:00:19.55 bitrate= 120.3kbits/s speed=1.48x     D: size=
> 301kB time=00:00:20.43 bitrate= 120.6kbits/s speed=1.49x     D: size=
> 314kB time=00:00:21.29 bitrate= 120.9kbits/s speed= 1.5x     D: size=
> 327kB time=00:00:22.12 bitrate= 121.2kbits/s speed= 1.5x     D: size=
> 340kB time=00:00:22.96 bitrate= 121.4kbits/s speed=1.51x     D: size=
> 354kB time=00:00:23.80 bitrate= 121.7kbits/s speed=1.51x     D: size=
> 367kB time=00:00:24.63 bitrate= 122.0kbits/s speed=1.51x     D: size=
> 379kB time=00:00:25.37 bitrate= 122.2kbits/s speed=1.51x     D: size=
> 388kB time=00:00:26.00 bitrate= 122.4kbits/s speed= 1.5x     D: size=
> 400kB time=00:00:26.74 bitrate= 122.5kbits/s speed= 1.5x     D: size=
> 411kB time=00:00:27.44 bitrate= 122.8kbits/s speed= 1.5x     D: size=
> 424kB time=00:00:28.25 bitrate= 123.0kbits/s speed= 1.5x     D: size=
> 437kB time=00:00:29.07 bitrate= 123.2kbits/s speed= 1.5x     D: size=
> 450kB time=00:00:29.86 bitrate= 123.4kbits/s speed= 1.5x     D: size=
> 463kB time=00:00:30.69 bitrate= 123.5kbits/s speed= 1.5x     D: size=
> 472kB time=00:00:31.30 bitrate= 123.6kbits/s speed= 1.5x     D: size=
> 484kB time=00:00:32.02 bitrate= 123.8kbits/s speed= 1.5x     D: size=
> 497kB time=00:00:32.85 bitrate= 123.9kbits/s speed= 1.5x     D: size=
> 511kB time=00:00:33.71 bitrate= 124.1kbits/s speed= 1.5x     D: size=
> 524kB time=00:00:34.55 bitrate= 124.2kbits/s speed=1.51x     D: size=
> 537kB time=00:00:35.38 bitrate= 124.3kbits/s speed=1.51x     D: size=
> 547kB time=00:00:36.06 bitrate= 124.4kbits/s speed=1.51x     D: size=
> 558kB time=00:00:36.73 bitrate= 124.4kbits/s speed= 1.5x     D: size=
> 570kB time=00:00:37.50 bitrate= 124.5kbits/s speed= 1.5x     D: size=
> 583kB time=00:00:38.31 bitrate= 124.6kbits/s speed= 1.5x     D: size=
> 593kB time=00:00:38.93 bitrate= 124.6kbits/s speed= 1.5x     D: size=
> 604kB time=00:00:39.65 bitrate= 124.7kbits/s speed= 1.5x     D: size=
> 617kB time=00:00:40.49 bitrate= 124.8kbits/s speed= 1.5x     D: size=
> 630kB time=00:00:41.33 bitrate= 124.9kbits/s speed= 1.5x     D: size=
> 643kB time=00:00:42.12 bitrate= 125.0kbits/s speed= 1.5x     D: size=
> 656kB time=00:00:42.95 bitrate= 125.0kbits/s speed=1.51x     D: size=
> 666kB time=00:00:43.58 bitrate= 125.2kbits/s speed= 1.5x     D: size=
> 679kB time=00:00:44.41 bitrate= 125.3kbits/s speed= 1.5x     D: size=
> 692kB time=00:00:45.23 bitrate= 125.3kbits/s speed=1.51x     D: size=
> 704kB time=00:00:45.97 bitrate= 125.4kbits/s speed=1.51x     D: size=
> 717kB time=00:00:46.78 bitrate= 125.5kbits/s speed=1.51x     D: size=
> 731kB time=00:00:47.69 bitrate= 125.6kbits/s speed=1.51x     D: size=
> 743kB time=00:00:48.43 bitrate= 125.6kbits/s speed=1.51x     D: size=
> 753kB time=00:00:49.06 bitrate= 125.7kbits/s speed=1.51x     D: size=
> 766kB time=00:00:49.92 bitrate= 125.7kbits/s speed=1.51x     D: size=
> 782kB time=00:00:50.94 bitrate= 125.8kbits/s speed=1.52x     D: size=
> 796kB time=00:00:51.85 bitrate= 125.8kbits/s speed=1.52x     D: size=
> 810kB time=00:00:52.68 bitrate= 125.9kbits/s speed=1.52x     D: size=
> 823kB time=00:00:53.52 bitrate= 125.9kbits/s speed=1.52x     D: size=
> 835kB time=00:00:54.31 bitrate= 126.0kbits/s speed=1.52x     D: size=
> 848kB time=00:00:55.12 bitrate= 126.0kbits/s speed=1.53x     D: size=
> 861kB time=00:00:55.96 bitrate= 126.1kbits/s speed=1.53x     D: size=
> 874kB time=00:00:56.74 bitrate= 126.1kbits/s speed=1.53x     D: size=
> 887kB time=00:00:57.58 bitrate= 126.2kbits/s speed=1.53x     D: size=
> 900kB time=00:00:58.39 bitrate= 126.2kbits/s speed=1.53x     D: size=
> 913kB time=00:00:59.23 bitrate= 126.2kbits/s speed=1.53x     D: size=
> 926kB time=00:01:00.07 bitrate= 126.3kbits/s speed=1.53x     D: size=
> 939kB time=00:01:00.90 bitrate= 126.3kbits/s speed=1.53x     D: size=
> 952kB time=00:01:01.74 bitrate= 126.3kbits/s speed=1.54x     D: size=
> 965kB time=00:01:02.57 bitrate= 126.4kbits/s speed=1.54x     D: size=
> 978kB time=00:01:03.41 bitrate= 126.4kbits/s speed=1.54x     D: size=
> 992kB time=00:01:04.27 bitrate= 126.4kbits/s speed=1.54x     D: size=
> 1005kB time=00:01:05.10 bitrate= 126.4kbits/s speed=1.54x     D: size=
> 1018kB time=00:01:05.94 bitrate= 126.5kbits/s speed=1.54x     D: size=
> 1031kB time=00:01:06.78 bitrate= 126.5kbits/s speed=1.54x     D: size=
> 1044kB time=00:01:07.61 bitrate= 126.5kbits/s speed=1.55x     D: size=
> 1058kB time=00:01:08.45 bitrate= 126.6kbits/s speed=1.55x     D: size=
> 1071kB time=00:01:09.33 bitrate= 126.6kbits/s speed=1.55x     D: size=
> 1085kB time=00:01:10.17 bitrate= 126.6kbits/s speed=1.55x     D: size=
> 1098kB time=00:01:11.00 bitrate= 126.6kbits/s speed=1.55x     D: size=
> 1110kB time=00:01:11.79 bitrate= 126.7kbits/s speed=1.55x     D: size=
> 1123kB time=00:01:12.63 bitrate= 126.7kbits/s speed=1.55x     D: size=
> 1135kB time=00:01:13.37 bitrate= 126.7kbits/s speed=1.55x     D: size=
> 1149kB time=00:01:14.23 bitrate= 126.8kbits/s speed=1.55x     D: size=
> 1161kB time=00:01:15.04 bitrate= 126.8kbits/s speed=1.55x     D: size=
> 1175kB time=00:01:15.88 bitrate= 126.8kbits/s speed=1.55x     D: size=
> 1188kB time=00:01:16.71 bitrate= 126.8kbits/s speed=1.56x     D: size=
> 1201kB time=00:01:17.53 bitrate= 126.9kbits/s speed=1.56x     D: size=
> 1214kB time=00:01:18.36 bitrate= 126.9kbits/s speed=1.56x     D: size=
> 1225kB time=00:01:19.04 bitrate= 126.9kbits/s speed=1.55x     D: size=
> 1238kB time=00:01:19.87 bitrate= 127.0kbits/s speed=1.56x     D: size=
> 1251kB time=00:01:20.68 bitrate= 127.0kbits/s speed=1.56x     D: size=
> 1264kB time=00:01:21.52 bitrate= 127.0kbits/s speed=1.56x     D: size=
> 1276kB time=00:01:22.29 bitrate= 127.1kbits/s speed=1.56x     D: size=
> 1287kB time=00:01:22.94 bitrate= 127.1kbits/s speed=1.55x     D: size=
> 1298kB time=00:01:23.66 bitrate= 127.1kbits/s speed=1.54x     D: size=
> 1308kB time=00:01:24.26 bitrate= 127.1kbits/s speed=1.54x     D: size=
> 1321kB time=00:01:25.10 bitrate= 127.1kbits/s speed=1.54x     D: size=
> 1333kB time=00:01:25.91 bitrate= 127.1kbits/s speed=1.54x     D: size=
> 1345kB time=00:01:26.63 bitrate= 127.2kbits/s speed=1.54x     D: size=
> 1358kB time=00:01:27.39 bitrate= 127.3kbits/s speed=1.54x     D: size=
> 1370kB time=00:01:28.14 bitrate= 127.3kbits/s speed=1.54x     D: size=
> 1380kB time=00:01:28.76 bitrate= 127.3kbits/s speed=1.54x     D: size=
> 1388kB time=00:01:29.28 bitrate= 127.3kbits/s speed=1.53x     D: size=
> 1401kB time=00:01:30.11 bitrate= 127.4kbits/s speed=1.53x     D: size=
> 1408kB time=00:01:30.51 bitrate= 127.4kbits/s speed=1.53x     D: size=
> 1420kB time=00:01:31.32 bitrate= 127.4kbits/s speed=1.53x     D: size=
> 1432kB time=00:01:32.04 bitrate= 127.5kbits/s speed=1.53x     D: size=
> 1442kB time=00:01:32.67 bitrate= 127.5kbits/s speed=1.52x     D: size=
> 1455kB time=00:01:33.50 bitrate= 127.5kbits/s speed=1.53x     D: size=
> 1467kB time=00:01:34.24 bitrate= 127.5kbits/s speed=1.53x     D: size=
> 1480kB time=00:01:35.06 bitrate= 127.6kbits/s speed=1.53x     D: size=
> 1489kB time=00:01:35.57 bitrate= 127.6kbits/s speed=1.52x     D: size=
> 1499kB time=00:01:36.24 bitrate= 127.6kbits/s speed=1.52x     D: size=
> 1513kB time=00:01:37.05 bitrate= 127.7kbits/s speed=1.52x     D: size=
> 1527kB time=00:01:37.91 bitrate= 127.7kbits/s speed=1.52x     D: size=
> 1541kB time=00:01:38.80 bitrate= 127.7kbits/s speed=1.52x     D: size=
> 1554kB time=00:01:39.66 bitrate= 127.7kbits/s speed=1.52x     D: size=
> 1567kB time=00:01:40.51 bitrate= 127.7kbits/s speed=1.53x     D: size=
> 1580kB time=00:01:41.33 bitrate= 127.8kbits/s speed=1.53x     D: size=
> 1594kB time=00:01:42.19 bitrate= 127.8kbits/s speed=1.53x     D: size=
> 1607kB time=00:01:43.00 bitrate= 127.8kbits/s speed=1.53x     D: size=
> 1620kB time=00:01:43.83 bitrate= 127.8kbits/s speed=1.53x     D: size=
> 1633kB time=00:01:44.67 bitrate= 127.8kbits/s speed=1.53x     D: size=
> 1646kB time=00:01:45.53 bitrate= 127.8kbits/s speed=1.53x     D: size=
> 1659kB time=00:01:46.34 bitrate= 127.8kbits/s speed=1.53x     D: size=
> 1673kB time=00:01:47.18 bitrate= 127.8kbits/s speed=1.53x     D: size=
> 1686kB time=00:01:48.01 bitrate= 127.8kbits/s speed=1.53x     D: size=
> 1699kB time=00:01:48.85 bitrate= 127.8kbits/s speed=1.53x     D: size=
> 1712kB time=00:01:49.69 bitrate= 127.9kbits/s speed=1.53x     D: size=
> 1726kB time=00:01:50.57 bitrate= 127.9kbits/s speed=1.53x     D: size=
> 1740kB time=00:01:51.43 bitrate= 127.9kbits/s speed=1.54x     D: size=
> 1751kB time=00:01:52.12 bitrate= 127.9kbits/s speed=1.53x     D: size=
> 1764kB time=00:01:52.94 bitrate= 127.9kbits/s speed=1.54x     D: size=
> 1778kB time=00:01:53.87 bitrate= 127.9kbits/s speed=1.54x     D: size=
> 1790kB time=00:01:54.59 bitrate= 128.0kbits/s speed=1.54x     D: size=
> 1803kB time=00:01:55.40 bitrate= 128.0kbits/s speed=1.54x     D: size=
> 1816kB time=00:01:56.26 bitrate= 128.0kbits/s speed=1.54x     D: size=
> 1829kB time=00:01:57.07 bitrate= 128.0kbits/s speed=1.54x     D: size=
> 1842kB time=00:01:57.88 bitrate= 128.0kbits/s speed=1.54x     D: size=
> 1855kB time=00:01:58.70 bitrate= 128.0kbits/s speed=1.54x     D: size=
> 1866kB time=00:01:59.44 bitrate= 128.0kbits/s speed=1.54x     D: size=
> 1879kB time=00:02:00.27 bitrate= 128.0kbits/s speed=1.54x     D: size=
> 1892kB time=00:02:01.09 bitrate= 128.0kbits/s speed=1.54x     D: size=
> 1906kB time=00:02:01.92 bitrate= 128.0kbits/s speed=1.54x     D: size=
> 1918kB time=00:02:02.74 bitrate= 128.0kbits/s speed=1.54x     D: size=
> 1931kB time=00:02:03.57 bitrate= 128.0kbits/s speed=1.54x     D: size=
> 1945kB time=00:02:04.41 bitrate= 128.0kbits/s speed=1.54x     D: size=
> 1958kB time=00:02:05.22 bitrate= 128.1kbits/s speed=1.54x     D: size=
> 1971kB time=00:02:06.06 bitrate= 128.1kbits/s speed=1.54x     D: size=
> 1984kB time=00:02:06.87 bitrate= 128.1kbits/s speed=1.54x     D: size=
> 1995kB time=00:02:07.59 bitrate= 128.1kbits/s speed=1.54x     D: size=
> 2008kB time=00:02:08.42 bitrate= 128.1kbits/s speed=1.54x     D: size=
> 2022kB time=00:02:09.31 bitrate= 128.1kbits/s speed=1.54x     D: size=
> 2035kB time=00:02:10.14 bitrate= 128.1kbits/s speed=1.54x     D: size=
> 2048kB time=00:02:10.93 bitrate= 128.1kbits/s speed=1.55x     D: size=
> 2061kB time=00:02:11.75 bitrate= 128.1kbits/s speed=1.55x     D: size=
> 2074kB time=00:02:12.56 bitrate= 128.1kbits/s speed=1.55x     D: size=
> 2087kB time=00:02:13.39 bitrate= 128.1kbits/s speed=1.55x     D: size=
> 2100kB time=00:02:14.21 bitrate= 128.2kbits/s speed=1.55x     D: size=
> 2112kB time=00:02:15.00 bitrate= 128.2kbits/s speed=1.55x     D: size=
> 2125kB time=00:02:15.81 bitrate= 128.2kbits/s speed=1.55x     D: size=
> 2137kB time=00:02:16.53 bitrate= 128.2kbits/s speed=1.55x     D: size=
> 2150kB time=00:02:17.34 bitrate= 128.2kbits/s speed=1.55x     D: size=
> 2163kB time=00:02:18.18 bitrate= 128.2kbits/s speed=1.55x     D: size=
> 2175kB time=00:02:18.99 bitrate= 128.2kbits/s speed=1.55x     D: size=
> 2188kB time=00:02:19.80 bitrate= 128.2kbits/s speed=1.55x     D: size=
> 2200kB time=00:02:20.55 bitrate= 128.2kbits/s speed=1.55x     D: size=
> 2211kB time=00:02:21.17 bitrate= 128.3kbits/s speed=1.55x     D: size=
> 2221kB time=00:02:21.78 bitrate= 128.3kbits/s speed=1.54x     D: size=
> 2232kB time=00:02:22.52 bitrate= 128.3kbits/s speed=1.54x     D: size=
> 2246kB time=00:02:23.36 bitrate= 128.3kbits/s speed=1.54x     D: size=
> 2258kB time=00:02:24.10 bitrate= 128.3kbits/s speed=1.54x     D: size=
> 2270kB time=00:02:24.84 bitrate= 128.4kbits/s speed=1.54x     D: size=
> 2279kB time=00:02:25.42 bitrate= 128.4kbits/s speed=1.54x     D: size=
> 2288kB time=00:02:25.98 bitrate= 128.4kbits/s speed=1.54x     D: size=
> 2300kB time=00:02:26.72 bitrate= 128.4kbits/s speed=1.54x     D: size=
> 2308kB time=00:02:27.23 bitrate= 128.4kbits/s speed=1.53x     D: size=
> 2317kB time=00:02:27.77 bitrate= 128.5kbits/s speed=1.53x     D: size=
> 2327kB time=00:02:28.35 bitrate= 128.5kbits/s speed=1.53x     D: size=
> 2334kB time=00:02:28.77 bitrate= 128.5kbits/s speed=1.52x     D: size=
> 2342kB time=00:02:29.30 bitrate= 128.5kbits/s speed=1.52x     D: size=
> 2355kB time=00:02:30.11 bitrate= 128.5kbits/s speed=1.52x     D: size=
> 2364kB time=00:02:30.67 bitrate= 128.5kbits/s speed=1.52x     D: size=
> 2374kB time=00:02:31.27 bitrate= 128.5kbits/s speed=1.52x     D: size=
> 2386kB time=00:02:32.02 bitrate= 128.6kbits/s speed=1.52x     D: size=
> 2398kB time=00:02:32.76 bitrate= 128.6kbits/s speed=1.52x     D: size=
> 2411kB time=00:02:33.60 bitrate= 128.6kbits/s speed=1.52x     D: size=
> 2422kB time=00:02:34.27 bitrate= 128.6kbits/s speed=1.52x     D: size=
> 2435kB time=00:02:35.13 bitrate= 128.6kbits/s speed=1.52x     D: size=
> 2448kB time=00:02:35.87 bitrate= 128.6kbits/s speed=1.52x     D: size=
> 2460kB time=00:02:36.64 bitrate= 128.7kbits/s speed=1.52x     D: size=
> 2472kB time=00:02:37.40 bitrate= 128.7kbits/s speed=1.52x     D: size=
> 2485kB time=00:02:38.22 bitrate= 128.7kbits/s speed=1.52x     D: size=
> 2496kB time=00:02:38.89 bitrate= 128.7kbits/s speed=1.52x     D: size=
> 2509kB time=00:02:39.70 bitrate= 128.7kbits/s speed=1.52x     D: size=
> 2519kB time=00:02:40.35 bitrate= 128.7kbits/s speed=1.51x     D: size=
> 2530kB time=00:02:41.00 bitrate= 128.7kbits/s speed=1.51x     D: size=
> 2539kB time=00:02:41.61 bitrate= 128.7kbits/s speed=1.51x     D: size=
> 2553kB time=00:02:42.47 bitrate= 128.7kbits/s speed=1.51x     D: size=
> 2566kB time=00:02:43.28 bitrate= 128.7kbits/s speed=1.51x     D: size=
> 2578kB time=00:02:44.07 bitrate= 128.7kbits/s speed=1.51x     D: size=
> 2591kB time=00:02:44.86 bitrate= 128.7kbits/s speed=1.51x     D: size=
> 2602kB time=00:02:45.55 bitrate= 128.8kbits/s speed=1.51x     D: size=
> 2615kB time=00:02:46.39 bitrate= 128.8kbits/s speed=1.51x     D: size=
> 2628kB time=00:02:47.18 bitrate= 128.8kbits/s speed=1.51x     D: size=
> 2641kB time=00:02:47.99 bitrate= 128.8kbits/s speed=1.51x     D: size=
> 2649kB time=00:02:48.53 bitrate= 128.8kbits/s speed=1.51x     D: size=
> 2657kB time=00:02:49.04 bitrate= 128.8kbits/s speed=1.51x     D: size=
> 2671kB time=00:02:49.85 bitrate= 128.8kbits/s speed=1.51x     D: size=
> 2681kB time=00:02:50.50 bitrate= 128.8kbits/s speed=1.51x     D: size=
> 2691kB time=00:02:51.10 bitrate= 128.8kbits/s speed=1.51x     D: size=
> 2703kB time=00:02:51.89 bitrate= 128.8kbits/s speed=1.51x     D: size=
> 2716kB time=00:02:52.71 bitrate= 128.8kbits/s speed=1.51x     D: size=
> 2729kB time=00:02:53.47 bitrate= 128.9kbits/s speed=1.51x     D: size=
> 2741kB time=00:02:54.26 bitrate= 128.9kbits/s speed=1.51x     D: size=
> 2753kB time=00:02:55.00 bitrate= 128.9kbits/s speed=1.51x     D: size=
> 2766kB time=00:02:55.79 bitrate= 128.9kbits/s speed=1.51x     D: size=
> 2779kB time=00:02:56.65 bitrate= 128.9kbits/s speed=1.51x     D: size=
> 2792kB time=00:02:57.44 bitrate= 128.9kbits/s speed=1.51x     D: size=
> 2806kB time=00:02:58.32 bitrate= 128.9kbits/s speed=1.51x     D: size=
> 2819kB time=00:02:59.14 bitrate= 128.9kbits/s speed=1.51x     D: size=
> 2831kB time=00:02:59.90 bitrate= 128.9kbits/s speed=1.51x     D: size=
> 2844kB time=00:03:00.74 bitrate= 128.9kbits/s speed=1.51x     D: size=
> 2878kB time=00:03:03.27 bitrate= 128.6kbits/s speed=1.53x     D:
> video:0kB audio:2846kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global
> headers:0kB muxing overhead: 1.109895% D: [aac @ 0xf2a70c00] Qavg:
> 2111.697

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Share full log.

Comment: @Gyan what log you are expecting? total logs while trimming?

Comment: ffmpeg's log, written to stderr

Comment: It is converting successfully without any error, but time taking for conversion is too high.

Comment: Share full log.

Comment: @Gyan updated the question with log.

Answer (score 2):

The 3.0 release branch is old. Try a newer version. It will likely be faster as the default `-aac_coder` option value [changed](https://git.videolan.org/gitweb.cgi/ffmpeg.git/?a=commit;h=fcb681ac3edd708f26c3b5014c06e32fd2723887) from `twoloop` to `fast`. This change is missing in the 3.0 branch.

Alternatively, you can simply add the `-aac_coder fast` output option, but I recommend updating instead as you're missing some other relevant changes.

As for `-preset ultrafast` that's a [private option](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#AVOptions) for some video encoders as mentioned in your log:

```
AVOption preset (Set the encoding preset (cf. x264 --fullhelp)) specified for output file
#0 (/storage/emulated/0/SACLO.m4a) has not been used for any stream. The most likely reason
is either wrong type (e.g. a video option with no video streams) or that it is a private
option of some encoder which was not actually used for any stream.
```

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer, i just tried with -aac_coder fast, but getting error as   " Unrecognized option 'aac_coder fast' ".

Comment: @SachinVarma Works for me using 3.0.1. Make sure you're using it as an output option. Regardless, your `ffmpeg` is old. Your old version requires `-strict experimental` (or `-strict -2`) to use `-aac_coder` as mentioned in the log. You should upgrade.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard can you provide a way to use 3.0.1 without using NDK? I mean as gradle or aar file

Comment: @RohanKandwal I'm not an Android user and don't know anything about NDK, gradle, or AAR.